# Doxygen - how to document a variable so I can see its type

Tags: doxygen

I'm sorry if it sounds too simple a question but still ...

I am documenting php code and whereas all functions etc. look good in the generated documentation, 
I have problems with variable types which should be visible in the generated documentation.

I document them in this way:

```
    /**
      * $request - request object 
      * 
      * @type int
      * @access private
      */
     private $request;
```

As a result, I can see 'int' in the generated documentation, but `@type` is not a correct command. The proper command would be `@var` instead of `@type` but then I cannot see the type of the variable in the documentation.
So the question is "*How to document a variable so I can see its type?*"
Please help :)